# Paypal Form Inside ASP.NET Form

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Cheers,

I have a problem with integrating Paypal Shopping Cart to my ASP.NET C# project.
The problem is that Paypal Shopping Cart is inside a FORM tag, so if I place that inside my server form tag it won't work.

It would look like this:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MySecretEmail@hidden.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_viewcart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      </form>
</form>
</body>
```

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening? I've search on google and here on Stackoverflow where I found this link: [PayPal Name-Value Pair API Basics](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview), but honestly, it doesn't make any sense to me since I'm not a programmer.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you still looking for a suitable answer or can one of the below be accepted?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to use the PostBackUrl property of the asp:button. Using this method, the ASP generates your JavaScript to handle the external post.

This allows the rendering of the form to happen correctly and doesn't require any workaround. Remember that as your code is already in a form tag, your paypal items don't need to be wrapped in an extra  tag.

e.g.

```
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart'/>
<input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='business@business.com'/>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='aud'/>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number_1' value='item number_1'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='16x16 inch square canvas'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='70'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number_2' value='item number_2'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value=' 48x20 rectangular canvas'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='104'>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" PostBackUrl='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' runat="server" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've used this method with success for years until recently. When the button is clicked in a production environment (sandbox works fine), PayPal can show either a blank white page with a 502 status, or a message saying zero object size. This could be down to additional .net form data being passed conflicting with PayPal. Am unsure which form items are causing this, but have tested in it's own form which works without problems. This can also explain why it is intermitant where conflicting .net form items are present or absent. If this is the case, @SecretaryofRacing has an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your example isn't valid HTML. In the longer term, you might be best refactoring this code to remove your 'technical debt'. (See "must not contain other form elements" under element prohibitions on the [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions) for XHTML 1.0)

In the meantime, you could try submitting the nested form with `jQuery`.

### 1. Replace Submit Button

```
<button class="submit-button" id="submit-button">Submit Payment</button>
```

### 2. Amend Form Tag

```
<form id="nested-form" target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

### 3. Submit form using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit-button').live('click',function() {
    $('#nested-form').submit();
});
</script>
```

I haven't had a chance to test this, so please test and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply mate. But to be 100% honest with you, then your solution is a little too complicated for me, I'm not experienced.

Comment: @MikeBertelsen If you follow the three steps above (and add a reference in your 'head' tags to jQuery) - <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>, you should be able to achieve this. Let me know if you're having problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very easy method.  It's what I use exclusively so I know with 100% certainty that it works.

1. Create a "false" image only PayPal button.
2. User clicks this button (it's just an image)
3. This image has an onclick method which calls a 2 line javascript function (see below)
4. Put your "real" PayPal button form at the end of your page AFTER the closing form tag.
5. Enclose it in a SPAN tag with style="display:none;"
6. Add ID="ppsubmit" to the "real" button's image input
7. When user click the false button, the onclick method calls a javascript function that does just 2 things ... a) changes span display to inline and b) automatically clicks the real PayPal button.

   ```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <!-- Here's the image only "false" paypal button -->
   <input type="image"
   src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif"
   border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"
   onclick="javascript:doPPform();" />
   </form>  <!-- this closes your asp.net form -->

   <!-- Here's the hidden span with the real paypal button
        at the bottom of your webpage -->
   <span id="ppform" style="display: none;">
   <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"
    target="_top">
         <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
         <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxx">
         <input id="ppsubmit" type="image" 
             src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif"
             border="0" name="submit"
             alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
         <img alt="" border="0"
              src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
              width="1" height="1">
   </form>
   </span>

   <!-- Here's the 2 line javascript code when the user clicks the "false" button -->
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function doPPform() {
       document.getElementById("ppform").style.display = "inline";
       document.getElementById("ppsubmit").click();
   }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to put the paypal form inside an `iframe`.

On the form element, change `target="_parent"` so it posts back to the parent page.

Comment: I'm not much for using iFrames, I only heard "bad things" about them. Is there anything else I can use beside, an iFrame?

Comment: @MikeBertelsen My answer and the other answer are about as simple as you can get given you situation. Otherwise, dig into the API and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the page the payment form is on use a MasterPage that has the  tag removed. I do this on all the sites and it works without problems.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered the PayPal button problem before I discovered that it is an ASP.NET problem.
In the process of creating buttons and adding to my page, sometimes they would work and sometimes they would not. Then I would have 2 identical buttons and the second would work and the first would not. Remove the first and then the button that worked would not. To get to the point if I added a form tag before my PayPal button the Paypal button works.

```
<%-- simple form tag --%>
<form action="">
</form>

<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="hughet_1335403121_biz@yahoo.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input id="iptItemName" type="hidden" name="item_name" value="testBuyNow">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" 
    value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
  <input type="image" 
    src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"
    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" 
    src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
    width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I understand this a "hack fix", and I'm not sure why this works. Curious if this works for others.